# input string is not in a correct format

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I want to calculate the percentage. But the compiler is giving an error that the input string is not in a correct format. Can some one elaborate what i am missing here?

```
private double per()
{
  double a = Convert.ToDouble(tbEnglish.Text+tbUrdu.Text+tbPhysics.Text+tbChemistry.Text+tbMaths.Text);
  double d = 500;
  double lblResult = (a / d)*100;
  return lblResult;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're concatenating the strings and then trying to convert that one result into a double. So for results of 75.6, 92.1, 56.3 78.2 and 72.3 you'd end up trying to parse "75.692.156.378.272.3".

Parse each value and then sum them.

However, I would strongly recommend that you use `decimal` for this instead of `double`. You should also consider using `TryParse` instead of `Parse` so that you can handle user input errors gracefully. Here's the solution sticking with `Parse`:

```
public decimal AveragePercentage()
{
    decimal sum = decimal.Parse(tbEnglish.Text) +
                  decimal.Parse(tbUrdu.Text) +
                  decimal.Parse(tbPhysics.Text) +
                  decimal.Parse(tbChemistry.Text) +
                  decimal.Parse(tbMaths.Text);
    return sum / 5m;
}
```

Out of interest, in your original code why are you dividing by 500 and then multiplying by 100? Why not just divide by 5 (as mine does now that I've noticed what was going on)?

As a side note, it's very important to differentiate between *compile-time* errors and *execution-time* errors. It *wasn't* the compiler saying that the input string wasn't in the  correct format - it was the `Convert.ToDouble` method, at execution time. In this case it was relatively obvious, but in other situations we could have been chasing our tails for a while trying to find a compile-time problem when it was actually failing at execution time.

Comment: I feel like an idiot for asking, but what is the "500m" syntax? What's the 'm' do?

Comment: @Sapph: It indicates a numeric literal of the `decimal` type. (i.e. it's the decimal equivalent of `d` for double or `f` for float)

Comment: this AveragePercentage is a built in function huh?

Comment: @Sapph: You can do `var x = 5m;` and place your mouse over var to see the datatype it becomes.

Comment: @jon Skeet : i`m not getting this Averagepercentage function in my compiler! :/

Comment: @Abid: `AveragePercentage` is not a built-in function at all. Jon Skeet just showed you how to write it! :) Not to put words in his mouth, but he may have been suggesting that "AveragePercentage" is a clearer name for your "per" function.

Comment: ohh.. :) such a foolish of me.. btw.. the function by JON also gives the same exception... i don`t know why..

Comment: @abid: that suggests there's something wrong with your data. What are the values in your textboxes? (This is why you should use TryParse btw - you can validate the user input without an exception.)

Comment: i`m giving value like 34.6 65.4 63.8

Comment: @Abid: Which line is throwing the exception, and what's the value for the corresponding textbox? Also, what's the default culture for your box?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Visual Studio available to me here on my Linux box, but I think you're better off with code like this.

```
private double per()
{
   double a = Convert.ToDouble(tbEnglish.Text);
   a += Convert.ToDouble(tbPhysics.Text);
   a += Convert.ToDouble(tbChemistry.Text);
   a += Convert.ToDouble(tbMaths.Text);
   double d = 500;
   double lblResult = (a / d)*100;
   return lblResult;
}
```

In your example, you end up building a *string* that will look like: "75.692.156.372.3", which cannot be parsed into a double.

You need to convert all the TextBox.Text values into Decimals before using the `+` operator.

Comment: @Dominic your snippet aint working too.. :/ i guess there`s a problem with my code...